# navigate ListViewItem through arrow Up and Down Keys in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox, listitem

I made a simple application where i have some `TextBoxes` and One `ListItemView`. When i enter a data into `Textbox` it shows result in `ListItemView` from database. And when i press Arrow keys Down it focus on `ListItemView` and then i `Navigate` `ListItemView` Through arrow key `Up` and `Down`. And when i pressed `Enter` in selected item of `ItemListView` it shows content from `ItemListView` to `TextBox`. That's All my Purpose But the problem is how can i do it?

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
Always __TAG__ your question correctly!

Comment: my application is in Winforms

Comment: But Can i Make this in Java Please Help in Java

Comment: What is your problem? Why do you suddenly talk about java? Why do you call a ListView a ListItemView  and a ListViewItem? Never post code as an answer that isn't an answer; you can always edit the question. To set Focus on a Control use the control.Focus function. Note that no selection show unless you also select an item...As it stands the question is very bad.

Answer (score -1):

I use this code

`if(e.KeyCode==Keys.F1){
 this.ActiveControl=listView1;}`